# Why does Scala have classes when it already has traits?

Tags: class, scala, traits

This may seem like a silly question, so bear with me...

Consider this REPL session:

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> val t = new T
<console>:8: error: trait T is abstract; cannot be instantiated
       val t = new T
               ^

scala> val t = new T {}
t: java.lang.Object with T = $anon$1@78db81f3

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> val c = new C
c: C = C@170a6001
```

We can use a trait just like a class, except that we have to add `{}` after the `new T`. In fact, we're essentially mixing `T` into `java.lang.Object`, which actually makes a lot of sense to me.

If we have members, again only the `{}` must be added:

```
scala> trait T2 { val s = "test" }
defined trait T2

scala> val t2 = new T2
<console>:8: error: trait T2 is abstract; cannot be instantiated
       val t2 = new T2
                ^

scala> val t2 = new T2 {}
t2: java.lang.Object with T2 = $anon$1@6a688d6f

scala> t2.s
res0: java.lang.String = test

scala> class C2 { val s = "test" }
defined class C2

scala> val c2 = new C2
c2: C2 = C2@73ea7821

scala> c2.s
res1: java.lang.String = test
```

If we have abstract members then the trait declaration is actually shorter by a few characters and, more importantly, more consistent in my eyes (no need to remember to put `abstract` in front of your declarations):

```
scala> trait T3 { val s: String }
defined trait T3

scala> val t3 = new T3 { val s = "test" }
t3: java.lang.Object with T3 = $anon$1@1f2f0ce9

scala> abstract class C3 { val s: String }
defined class C3

scala> val c3 = new C3 { val s = "test" }
c3: C3 = $anon$1@207a8313
```

If you forget that you must define some of the members, both ways give you compile errors:

```
scala> val badt3 = new T3 {}
<console>:7: error: object creation impossible, since value s in trait T3 of type String is not defined
       val badt3 = new T3 {}

scala> class BadC3 { val s: String }
<console>:8: error: class BadC3 needs to be abstract, since value s is not defined
       class BadC3 { val s: String }
```

And if we try to do more complex things then the power of traits naturally becomes further apparent:

```
scala> val t4 = new T with T2
t4: java.lang.Object with T with T2 = $anon$1@479e0994

scala> val c4 = new C with C2
<console>:9: error: class C2 needs to be a trait to be mixed in
       val c4 = new C with C2
```

So again I ask, why does Scala bother with classes at all when traits are apparently both simpler and more powerful?

I assume the reason is conceptual and actual compatibility with Java, but I wonder whether code compatability could have been maintained behind the scenes. As I understand it, Scala traits just become Java classes behind the scenes, so why couldn't the reverse happen and Scala consider Java classes to essentially be traits?

Related to all this, why not allow dropping the curly brackets when unnecessary? For example:

```
val t = new T
```

At that point, *as a user*, traits would be indistinguishable from current Scala classes, but of course better.

Comment: Every time you write `new T {}` you create a new anonymous class. Not the kind of overhead you want. Besides, several "instances" of `T` won't have the same type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several differences between traits and classes:

- a trait can not take constructor parameters. This limitation might be lifted at some point, but it's a hard problem. A trait may be inherited multiple times in a hierarchy, and each instantiation may give different values for the constructor parameters
- a trait is compiled to a Java interface and an implementation class (carrying the concrete methods). This means it's a bit slower, because all calls go through interfaces, and if they're concrete, they are forwarded to their implementation
- a trait with concrete members can't be nicely inherited in Java (it could, but it would look like an interface, therefore concrete members would still need to be implemented in Java).

I don't think the distinction between classes and traits will go away, mostly because of the last two items. But they may become easier to use if the first point is solved. Regarding instantiation without the `{}`, that's a convenience that could be added, but I personally wouldn't like it: each instantiation creates a new **class** (an anonymous one), and there should be an indication to the programmer that that's the case.

Comment: Note that HotSpot (at least) will perform Type Sharpening. As those traits will be turned into interfaces which have only 1 implementation, those calls to trait methods will be sharpened from invokeinterface to invokevirtual. So your comment about method calls being slower probably doesn't hold in the majority of cases.

Comment: @kittylyst, you are right about the JVM. However, traits have many implementations (from the JVM's perspective). Each time a trait is mixed-in in a class, the corresponding interface is re-implemented by that class. For a long-running application with relatively few uses of a trait, its methods may be inlined optimistically, but at least start-up time would be affected. Where can I read more about Type Sharpening?

Comment: However, consider this... if traits got constructor parameters, and the proposal to auto-generate classes for each trait, and use it instead of the trait if that's the leftmost extension, then the problem with Java implementation and interoperability would mostly disappear, wouldn't they?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral you're right. I'd be very interested to see the benefits in the current collection library.